# Compiling Bochs 2.4.6 under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, compilation, bochs

Could anyone tell me a version of `Cygwin` that can compile successfully `Bochs 2.4.6`? I've tried with the latest version of `Cygwin (1.7.9(0.237/5/3))` but I ran into a bunch of errors.

In specific, I initially got a `C compiler cannot create executables` error when trying to `./configure` Bochs:

```
...
...
checking if you are configuring for another platform... no
checking for standard CFLAGS on this platform... -mno-cygwin -DWIN32
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/bochs-2.4.6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I solved this by switching my default gcc to version 3.x by using /usr/bin/set-gcc-default-3.sh. However, although the progress of the build was going great, I finally got a `DEPRECATED` error:

```
configure: error: DEPRECATED - moved to .bochsrc options
```

Now, I don't know how to overcome the last error so I am stucked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please? What exactly do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Bochs software package. Also, you might want to provide some of the errors.

Comment: A link to the Bochs sources I used is here [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bochs/files/bochs/2.4.6/bochs-2.4.6.tar.gz/download). I edited the OP and it now includes the errors I am getting.